# Which index does iterator pointing to

Tags: c++, iterator

There is an iterator to a vector. I want to know which index does iterator pointing to. So I made following but I am not sure.

```
int temp = -1;
std::vector <int> ::iterator f;

for (f=eFace[e].begin(); f!=eFace[e].end(); ++f)
{
    if (*f == face)
{
    switch (f-eFace[e].begin())
    {
        case 0:
        temp = 5;                                   
        break;
        case 1:
        temp = 3;
        break;
        case 2:
        temp = 4;
        break;
        case 3:
        temp = 1;
        break;
        case 4:
        temp = 2;
        break;
        case 5:
        temp = 0;
        break;
            default:
        throw;
    }

    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your bigger target? are you sure you need iterators and indices at the same time?

Comment: @phresnel, I find this most useful for output. I would venture a guess that the goal might be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like this :

```
std::vector <int> ::iterator f;

int index = 0;

for (f=eFace[e].begin(); f!=eFace[e].end(); ++f)
{
     // do sth

     index++;
}
```

Comment: And in bigger loops this would have a considerable difference in time compared to subtracting/calling distance each time.

Comment: Why not putting incrementation of `index` alongside the incrementation of `f` to avoid them getting out of sync ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. That would be an interesting addition. ;-)

Comment: @phresnel: misunderstood the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<int>::size_type index = std::distance (eFace [e].begin(), f);
```

Note that this can be slow if you execute it every loop though. Another option for vectors would be:

```
std::vector<int>::size_type index = f - eFace [e].begin();
```

This works because vectors use a random-access iterator, which is required to have subtraction defined, as pointed out by Steve Jessop below.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's actually required by the standard, but if `std::distance` doesn't have constant time-complexity for iterators tagged as random access (which vector iterators are), then that's pretty poor QoI even if it conforms. Note that subtraction for random-access iterators is defined as `b - a == (a<b)?distance(a,b):-distance(b,a)`, so if you're worried about bad implementations you could just as well worry that subtraction is slow!

Comment: @SteveJessop, that's an interesting point. I wasn't aware that subtraction was implemented like that. My answer pointed to a more one-line approach than two different parts of setting up the index variable and incrementing it. It is rather inefficient in bigger loops.

Comment: In practice I expect subtraction *isn't* implemented like that, it's just that the result is defined in the standard as that value. So if we're speculating about stupidly slow implementations of `distance`, we can speculate that subtraction is stupid too. In fact, they will both be fast in any implementation fit for real use. Btw, the thing that makes subtraction work for vectors isn't that the storage is contiguous, it's that the iterator is random-access and hence must have subtraction defined. For example, `deque` uses non-contiguous storage, but iterator subtraction works for that too.

Answer (score 2):

Getting clearer code would be much easier.

First, finding a value in a vector:

```
// Returns the index of `face` in `vec`.
// If `face` is not present in `vec`, returns `vec.size()`.
size_t findFaceIndex(int const face, std::vector<int> const& vec) {
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator const it =
        std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), face);

    return it - vec.begin();
}
```

And now mapping:

```
static int const FaceMap[] = { 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0 };
static size_t const FaceMapSize = sizeof(FaceMap)/sizeof(int);

// Translate face index into ...
int faceIndexToX(size_t const index) {
    if (index >= FaceMapSize) { throw std::runtime_error("out of bounds"); }
    return FaceMap[index];
}
```

Comment: The first of those could be templated, of course. In general there's a warning sign if anyone uses std::find as it uses linear search. It's good enough on rare occasions, small collection, infrequently called.

Second solution of yours is better albeit there is no such exception as std::runtime_exception (there is runtime_error but std::out_of_range is probably the better one to throw like vector::at does, although I'd prefer context or an assert.

Comment: @CashCow: I considered a `std::array` but I am not sure if the OP is C++11 savvy. It would be much easier of course.

Answer (score 0):

For your question "I want to know which index does iterator pointing to." by saying `std::vector<int>::iterator f = eFace.begin();` you are creating an interator that would be similar to the index approach by saying `std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;`.

With iterators you use `eFace.begin()` and `!= eFace.end()` the same way you would use `i = 0` and `!= eFace.size()` when walking through a vector with a `for` loop.

At least I think that's what your original question was.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you need the index of an array when you have the iterator anyway? Provided the iterator is random access you *can* subtract it from `begin()`, but if the index is so important I wonder if you're better off just using that rather than an iterator  - of course it depends on whether you have access to the code to refactor it.

I'm not sure quite what you're trying to achieve with your switch but if it's to map values then presumably a sparse vector would be far more appropriate?